# Oracle Abort rollback transaction

Tags: oracle, merge, transactions, rollback

There is a long running transaction(MERGE statement of 100000000 rows) which update table  CDM.MA_CONTACT. We decide to kill the session using "alter system kill session". But it takes a long time to rollback, I think, about 50 hours.
So, I must to run some other merge statements but I cant do it, because table is locked.
Can I abort this rollback or unlock this table?

Comment: You're probably stuck waiting for the rollback unless you want to shutdown the database ungracefully and recover to a backup. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238932/how-to-stop-oracle-undo-process

Comment: No, I dont want to shutdown this database

Comment: It may be faster to recreate table as CTAS and do merge on new copy. The question is if you can do that.

Comment: But I have many scripts which have merge statement, it could be diffucult to edit them and rename this table. May be there is some other way? For example, create a synonym?