# After process delete and abort deleting oracle working very slow

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a database `oracle 11g`, after process `delete` and abort deleting process oracle working very slow, I restarted the server several times but did not help, that I see how I can fix the problem, please help

Comment: what did you delete?

Comment: I am delete data in table just about 25.000.000 rows, and I canceled this process, after canceling worked veri slow

Comment: deja vu all over again with this question ;-)  Oracle is/was rolling back the transaction.  Not sure what state it was in once you bounced the server tho

Comment: And how do I check the source of slowness

Answer (score 2):

Over simplifying:

When you aborted the delete statement, Oracle had already done some of the work deleting some of the rows. While deleting the rows Oracle was saving UNDO that is used by multi-version concurrency control for reading from other transactions until this one commits, and used in the case of rollback.

When you aborted the delete Oracle has to apply the UNDO to put those rows back into the table, because a delete statement is atomic. It either all happened or nothing happened. Applying UNDO is relatively slow and is going to be using resources until it is done. That extra work is not going to go away by restarting Oracle, Oracle will apply the UNDO until it is done.

Next step would be to investigate if resources are being spent applying the UNDO, or if the slowness has another cause. Unfortunately I can offer no help in troubleshooting.

One quick way to check the rollback progress is to run this query, wait a minute, run it again, and use that to estimate the number of minutes until the number shrinks to zero.  Once the rollback has started there is no way to stop it or improve it.  Restarting the server and killing processes won't speed it up.  You just have wait until that number gets to 0 and the row disappears.

```
select used_urec from gv$transaction;
```

Comment: Then if so leave it will fix itself after UNDO?

Comment: Yes, if applying the UNDO is the source of slowness, then resource will be freed up once that is done.

Comment: And how do I check the source of slowness

Comment: "Unfortunately I can offer no help in troubleshooting." I have been away from Oracle too long, skills have been forgotten.

Comment: thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

If you have no more data in your table try to do `truncate` your table, with this clause you'll clear memory and your query will be fast again.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE employees_demo;
```

more details here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10007.htm#SQLRF01707

the same questions [How to stop oracle undo process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238932/how-to-stop-oracle-undo-process)

Comment: this process aborted, after this I am a restarted the server several times but did not help

Comment: @AniSevanyan yes, I understand. Can you make queries to your table?

Comment: yes, database working, but veri slow compared to the earlier

Comment: I can not do `truncate table` there is important information

Comment: I just wrote a simple query `delete from table1 where id not in (select table1_id from table2)` and after this oracle dead

Comment: @AniSevanyan it seems your answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238932/how-to-stop-oracle-undo-process